# Проблема с адаптивностью страницы под разные разрешения экранов

Tags: адаптивная-верстка

Надоело уже! Что бы ни делаю в одном хорошо, а в другом экране вонюче и криво все! Как исправить? Что должен я знать? Как эти дела ведутся(именно с разрешениями)?

Answer (score 1):

Зачем изобретать велосипед, если очень много умных людей на это уже потратили время и раздают готовые велосипеды совершенно даром.

Берешь готовый отлаженный фреймворк, заточенный для работы под разные разрешения - и не паришься. Например, http://foundation.zurb.com/